# How to put a degree symbol in an html input field through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ascii

I have a text box as

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="lat" placeholder="Latitude" ng-lat value="9&#176;">
```

which works fine as it displays the degree sign perfectly, but when I try to set the value through jquery like

**Jquery**

`$("#lat").val("9&#176;")`

Its displaying the entire text instead of the degree symbol.

Comment: I would suggest you put the unit outside the `input`, otherwise you're crating a headache to make sure that the unit is present in the entered value, and also in the right place. Leave it outside, and append it as needed before sending it to the server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - this should be an ans

Comment: I have thought of that but I need to show latitude details (degree, minutes, second )in a single text box and the requirement is to add the degree sign there.

Comment: @BiJ If that's the case I would look in to input masking

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can target the `value` attribute:

```
$("#lat").attr('value',"101"+String.fromCharCode(176))
```

it is also better to use `.text()` to set the text because `.val()` is used to retrieve the value of an element

Answer (score 6):

You can use HEXCode, 
e.g

```
 <a href id="my">Here</a> 
<script>
    $('#my').click(function()
                    {
    alert('9\xB0');
    });
    </script>
```

Also go through this [link](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathsymbols.htm)

Comment: Please note that 9 is not part of the code! `°` sign is just '\xB0'

Comment: @TheGodfather I've added 9 only as an example

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#test").click(function(){ 
    $("#lat").val("29" + ascii(176))
});

function ascii (a) { return String.fromCharCode(a); }
```

Updated JSFiddle for further help: http://jsfiddle.net/zkh2of12/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use the special tag besides the input field, it will be clear for the user:

```
<input type="text" id="lat" placeholder="Latitude &#176;" value=""> &#176;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just setting the symbol directly in JavaScript instead of the HTML code?

```js
$(function(){
  $("#set").click(function(){
    $("#lat").val("°");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="lat" placeholder="Latitude" ng-lat value="9&#176;"> 

<button id="set">set</button>
```

If you want to improve those just make a hidden `<span>` with the html code you like inside and then just pick the html with JavaScript. This will work even for symbols you cannot post in JS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#lat").attr("val","9"+ascii(176));
```

Comment: `ascii` is not defined.